# sql trigger cannot insert row using variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

When i use this code it inserts row

```
create trigger [dbo].[InsertInvPayment] on dbo.LG_001_01_PAYTRANS
after update
as
begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   declare @InvLogicalRef int;
   declare @InvNumber varchar(50);
   select @InvLogicalRef = inserted.FICHEREF from inserted
   select @InvNumber = dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE.DOCODE from dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE where      dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE.LOGICALREF = @InvLogicalRef
   insert into dbo.CRMINVPAYMENT(INVNUMBER) values('Hello')
  end
```

if i change it like this

```
create trigger [dbo].[InsertInvPayment] on dbo.LG_001_01_PAYTRANS
after update
as
begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   declare @InvLogicalRef int;
   declare @InvNumber varchar(50);
   select @InvLogicalRef = inserted.FICHEREF from inserted
   select @InvNumber = dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE.DOCODE from dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE where      dbo.LG_001_01_INVOICE.LOGICALREF = @InvLogicalRef
   insert into dbo.CRMINVPAYMENT(INVNUMBER) values(@InvNumber)
  end
```

it doesn't work. i couldn't find a mistake in the second

Comment: can you print values of @InvNumber?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. Error message? Unexpected results? Also, it's broken anyway. `inserted` may contain 0, 1 or *many* rows.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like You are missing the source for select InvLogicalRef. It should be

```
select @InvLogicalRef = inserted.FICHEREF from inserted
```

Also with this trigger you are assuming that only one record will update at once. This will fail for bulk updates.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you assign a value to @InvLogicalRef is incomplete.
As that variable doesn't contain a value, @InvNumber can't be assigned its value and you are therefore trying to insert a NULL string into CRMINVPAYMENT.

Make sure you select the value of @InvLogicalRef from the inserted table.